# How to Re-direct to API index page when accessing API Base Path?

Tags: java, rest, web.xml

I am developing a Java Dynamic Web Project with a REST service.

`http://localhost:8080/fire_monitor` loads the `index.html` .
But I want `http://localhost:8080/fire_monitor/api` also to be redirected to `index.html`.

How can I accomplish this from web.xml ?

here is my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
      <display-name>FireAlram Monitoring System - REST Service</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fire_rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>fireservice</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fire_rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

1. Renamed index.html to index.jsp ( both the file iteself and web.xml welcome-file)
2. Add the following to web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index.jsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>index.jsp</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```